# Ping returns from old host IP

Tags: ip, ubuntu-18.04, modem

I replaced my modem, and in the process of doing so all my device IP's were changed. As a result, I changed all the port forwarding settings, and edited the /etc/hosts file in my ubuntu webserver. As soon as I edited the hosts file to change the IP's to the new ones, the server lost internet connectivity. When I try to ping an internet destination, say 8.8.8.8, it returns this
`From 10.0.0.XX icmp_seq=10 Destination Host Unreachable`
Only problem is, that IP is the old one. I double checked /etc/hosts, but they're all updated. How can I fix this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

solved by running these commands on the local machine, NOT SSH

```
sudo dhclient

sudo dhclient -r

sudo dhclient
```

Comment: My gosh, after all the answer I've read so far saying to flush the dns records using commands that don't exist anymore, after finally flushing the dns records with no effect, you finally saved me!